# %*c in scanf() - what does it mean?

Tags: c, scanf

I tried to run this program in Turbo C but couldn't decipher the output. What does this `%*c` mean? Any help would be appreciated.

```
int dd,mm,yy;
printf("\n\tEnter day,month and year");
scanf("%d %*c %d %*c %d",&dd,&mm,&yy);  // what does %*c mean ?
printf("\n\tThe date is : %d %d %d",dd,mm,yy);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Enter day, month and year 23
2
1991
3
5
The date is: 23 1991 5
```

Comment: what if he wants to discard next 3 chars?

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık: You could use `%*3c` to specify the number of characters to be skipped.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `*` in a `scanf()` format means 'read the data but do not assign it to a variable in the argument list'.  In context, it means you could type:

```
18/07/2012
```

and get the day (18), month (7) and year (2012) interpreted correctly.  The spaces in the format string are crucial and complicate things.  Normally, `%c` reads the next character, even a space, but the spaces around the `%*c` conversion specifiers deal with white space, so the code needs a non-blank character to consume.

Hence the observed behaviour that when you typed:

```
23 2 1991 3 5
```

the 2 (on its own) was consumed by the first `%*c` and the 3 (on its own) was consumed by the second.

This is Standard C and not a peculiar feature of Turbo C (which the first edition of the question specified, but the question has been edited to remove the reference to Turbo C since I first wrote this answer).

Comment: I guess I didn't know this.Thanks Anyhow !

Answer (score 6):

The `*` after `%` in a format string signify that the input matching the format will be ignored (thus no need to pass in a pointer to a variable to store the matched value that you are not going to use).

Answer (score 3):

It means to ignore the next character such as a space, `/`, or a `-` that is common in written dates.

Answer (score 1):

Use `*` with `scanf` suppresses assignment. The result of the conversion that follows is discarded.